# when populating cells I get a Runtime error 13 after running for a few cells

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, vlookup, auto-populate

I am trying to build a code that will help me populate a list with the team names based on 2 different tables in another worksheet.

The code actually runs quite well for the first 10 cells, and then I suddenly get a Runtime error 13 "Type mismatch" and I cannot figure what is wrong with it

the code I have is

```
Sub populateteam()

Dim wsAkasaka As Worksheet
Dim wsList As Worksheet

Set wsAkasaka = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Akasaka")
Set wsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Japan")

Dim consultant As String
Dim manager As String
Dim team As String

consultant = wsAkasaka.Range("b" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("a13:c200"), 3, False)
team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("E2:F11"), 2, False)

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
ActiveCell.Value = team
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If


End Sub
```

If anyone could give me a light for why this is happening and how could I fix it.

- Edit
  I forgot to write I get the error on the "team" declaration,
  I took it out and ran the code populating with "manager" and had no problem with it, but when I ask for the team I get the error

Comment: In which line of the code do you get the error?

Comment: Check the spelling of the manager name in both sheets (including spaces at the end) - if it doesn't appear in the table you get the error.

Comment: Thank you! Spaces at the end... I should have figured. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you define your variables `As String` and if your `VLookup` returns an error (in case `VLookup` doesn't find anything), this error cannot be cast into a `String` and you get a *Mismatch Error*.

Therefore I recommend the following:

```
' your code here …

Dim consultant As String
consultant = wsAkasaka.Range("b" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value

Dim manager As Variant
manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("a13:c200"), 3, False)

If IsError(manager) Then  ' check if consultant was found, if not exit
    MsgBox "Consultant """ & consultant & """ not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim team As Variant
team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("E2:F11"), 2, False)

If IsError(team) Then  ' check if manager was found, if not exit
    MsgBox "Manager """ & manager & """ not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

' your code here …
```

Comment: I just fixed the manager names, but this code will help me so much in the future since the list will be updated periodically, as well as in other projects I have to work on. Thank you so so so much